# Sonar analysis for ExtendScript(JSX) files

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, extendscript, jsx

I have a list of files with .jsx extension which needs to be analyzed with Sonar. No plugin is available in Sonarqube for the same. Can anything be done to the existing JavaScript Sonar plugin to analyze .jsx files.

Anyone?

Comment: I agree, this would be very appreciated. Most of our scripts are in .jsx files, and even though we would change them to .js files I reckon it won't work, as it is potentially a different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

ExtendScript is based on ECMAScript (JavaScript). So you should be able to use Sonarqube for this. I wasn't sure about this (didn't know a thing about sonarqube -- now I do), but I plugged some jsx code into this demo, which uses sonarqube ...

http://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html#

and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Nope it does not work. SonarQube Javascript parser fails on JSX syntax. E.g.  ERROR - Parse error at line 63. It fails where in the render method you use HTML.